# Throttle Apache Spout Dynamically

Tags: timeout, apache-storm, throttling

I have a topology where spout reads data from Kafka and sends to bolt which in turn calls a REST API (A) and that calls another REST API (B). So far API B did not have throttling. Now they have implemented throttling (x number of max calls per clock minute).

We need to implement the throttling handler.

**Option A**

Initially we were thinking to do it in REST API (A) level and put a

`Thread.sleep(x in millis)` once the call is throttled by REST API (B)

but that will hold all the REST (A) calls waiting for that long (which will vary between 1 sec to 59 seconds) and that may increase the load for new calls coming in.

**Option B**

REST API (A) sends response back to Bolt about being throttled. Bolt notifies the Spout with process failure to

- To not to change the offset for those messages
- To tell spout to stop reading from Kafka and to stop emitting message to Bolt.
- Spout waits for some time (say a minute) and resumes from where it left

Option A is straight forward to implement but not a good solution in my opinion.

Trying to figure out if Option B is feasible with ***topology.max.spout.pending*** however how to dynamically communicate to Storm to put a throttling in spout. Anyone please can you share some thoughts on this option.

**Option C**

REST API (B) throttles the call from REST (A) which will not handle the same but will send the 429 response code to the bolt. The bolt will re-queue the message to a error topic part of another storm topology. This message can have retry count as part of it and in case the same message gets throttled again we can re-queue again with ++retry count.

Updating the post as found a solution to make the option B feasible.

**Option D**

https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/external/storm-kafka-client/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/KafkaSpoutRetryExponentialBackoff.java

```
/**
 * The time stamp of the next retry is scheduled according to the exponential backoff formula (geometric progression):
 * nextRetry = failCount == 1 ? currentTime + initialDelay : currentTime + delayPeriod^(failCount-1),
 * where failCount = 1, 2, 3, ... nextRetry = Min(nextRetry, currentTime + maxDelay).
 * <p/>
 * By specifying a value for maxRetries lower than Integer.MAX_VALUE, the user decides to sacrifice guarantee of delivery for the
 * previous polled records in favor of processing more records.
 *
 * @param initialDelay      initial delay of the first retry
 * @param delayPeriod       the time interval that is the ratio of the exponential backoff formula (geometric progression)
 * @param maxRetries        maximum number of times a tuple is retried before being acked and scheduled for commit
 * @param maxDelay          maximum amount of time waiting before retrying
 *
 */
public KafkaSpoutRetryExponentialBackoff(TimeInterval initialDelay, TimeInterval delayPeriod, int maxRetries, TimeInterval maxDelay) {
    this.initialDelay = initialDelay;
    this.delayPeriod = delayPeriod;
    this.maxRetries = maxRetries;
    this.maxDelay = maxDelay;
    LOG.debug("Instantiated {}", this.toStringImpl());
}
```

The steps will be as follows:

1. Create kafkaSpoutRetryService using the above constructor
2. Set retry to KafkaSpoutConfig using 
   `KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(kafkaBootStrapServers, topic).setRetry(kafkaSpoutRetryService)`
3. Fail the Bolt in case there is throttling in Rest API (B) using
   `collector.fail(tuple)` which will signal spout to process the tuple again, based in the retry configuration setup in step 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option D sounds fine, but in the interest of avoiding duplicates in calls to API A, I think you should consider separating your topology into two.

Have a topology that reads from your original Kafka topic (call it topic 1), calls REST API A, and writes whatever the output of the bolt is back to a Kafka topic (call it topic 2).

You then make a second topology whose only job is to read from topic 2, and call REST API B.

This will allow you to use option D while avoiding extra calls to API A when you are saturating API B. Your topologies will look like

Kafka 1 -> Bolt A -> REST API A -> Kafka 2
Kafka 2 -> Bolt B -> REST API B

If you want to make the solution a little more responsive to the throttling, you can use the `topology.max.spout.pending` configuration in Storm to limit how many tuples can be in-flight at the same time. You could then make your bolt B buffer in-flight tuples until the throttling expires, at which point you can make it try sending the tuples again. You can use `OutputCollector.resetTupleTimeout` to avoid the tuples timing out while Bolt B is waiting for the throttling to expire. You can use tick tuples to make Bolt B periodically wake up and check whether the throttling has expired.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am already using ````topology.max.spout.pending```` in my Storm configuration to manage the in-flight tuples. Also I have ````topology.message.timeout.secs```` configured so that all the retries can be completed within that timeframe. Regarding separating the topology it will be a change in architecture but definitely gives a food for thought. Will check back.